# Identifying a piece of Unicode

Tags: unicode

A group of people and I are worrying on solving something. I won't go into specifics, but we discovered a large swath of numbers and letters that are clearly part of what we're trying to solve. We tried a bunch of different things on them, and eventually found that decoding them as hex gave something promising. It's too long to paste in the whole thing, but here is a small portion of it:

```
ˆzHˆÎûR€jÖÚÞrC•úæçè)Ë@QRdvünZdPƒú§@Î
```

Someone who was working on it with us said the **`^z`** is a command in something and means we've probably done this correctly.

What I'm wondering here is **what to do next**.

I have very little coding knowledge. The person suggested that this is Unix and is somehow executable by windows, but that we would need to know more to tell what it was.
Thanks for your time, and sorry if this is the wrong kind of question for this forum.

The context is a website with nothing but the hex codes for this that someone found. The only other thing on the website is a link to a Dropbox with an exe that is a crudely made encryption/decryption tool that is in polish. There is no relevant context at all, which is most of the problem.

Comment: What makes you think it's Unicode?   If it is, then what encoding might make sense?

Comment: Your vagueness is not helping your cause at all. One good start would be to show the byte sequence as hex instead of characters.

Comment: If you want better help, you should post the link to the website, so we can see it in context.  Failing that, you should post the entire sequence in context (IE with the HTML that it comes inside of).

Comment: When you decoded as hex and printed, is the '^z' that we see one control character (hex 0x26) being rendered as ^z so we can see it) or two characters: an 'caret' then a 'z'?  This is the kind of thing we can't tell unless you share the raw sequence... and it makes a lot of difference.

Answer (score 0):

### Identification

To be able to identify anything, **all context details are indispensable.**

There are many pieces of information missing. Yes, there is a **`^z`** visible, but that need not mean it is a <<*control-code*>> ( which is a one-byte character, that is just visualised with a carret **`^`**-marker in front of a printable character, as the code itself is non-printable per-se ) and obviously it is not a <kbd>^Z</kbd> ( which you may see from lower-case "z" in your demo-string ). HEX-editors make this ambiguity a step clearer, as they show exact byte-values, octet by octet.

### Unicode?

Unicode is a convention, how to represent more than just a few characters in a world, where one-byte coding does not suffice to represent "longer" alphabets and how to have strings, where one can see text in more different alphabets directly one besides the other -- together -- like having text with French accents right after with Russian Azbuka and another Unicode-coded characters.

### Does the `code` know just by itself whether it is Unicode or not?

No. The code is just `00110101010001001001000100101010101011110111010110101101`
The context helps the world "outside" the code to handle the code in ways the context rather weakly "proposes".

### To be executable or not to be? That's the question

Again, there are some ways to "execute" a byte-stream, as a code.

Some of these ways/methods are intended ( as known in both Linux & Windows O/S, where well-formated files, that an operating system can pre-load, carry the code ), some other ways/methods are domains of white/gray hacking, some are even subject of a criminal activity, in case the colour of hacking turns dark to black, however **all aim at the same goal** -- to place a byte-stream code into a proper location in the system memory and then arrange a step to transfer a CPU-control, to start "running" the code, instruction after instruction.

So, without any detail, whether the sample string is a byte-stream, where it comes from, whether it is the header of a sequence, what was the file-name in case it was taken from some filesystem object, no one responsible ( even the Master of The Masters ) can answer your question what to do next.

Comment: I wish I had any more information, but essentially all we have is this and 30 or so more similar lines. No filename, no context, nothing. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, but where did it come from?  What "might" it be?   Are you saying "this is a file on a disk, this is the contents, what might this file be"?

Comment: One shall also know, **rather a-priori** any irreversible first-hand experience, that in some jurisdictions, the reverse-engineering of any code is considered a criminal offense.

Comment: The context is a website with nothing but the hex codes for this that someone found. The only other thing on the website is a link to a Dropbox with an exe that is a crudely made encryption/decryption tool that is in polish. There is no relevant context at all, which is most of the problem. My guess of what it might be is as good as anyone's.

Comment: Like this "answer", all these comments should be added as comments to the question, not appended here under this answer-that-really-just-a-comment.

Comment: @unKedRILL you say it's hex codes, but you don't give us hex codes to look at - you give us characters in some unknown encoding. That's totally worthless.

Comment: @user3666197 I'm making the comment directly in response to a comment left here. I tried to make the same point on the OP, in less forceful language, and it was ignored.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks for you kind explanation. Agree on vagueness and a lot of confusion / mis-concepts. Guiding such posts is not much welcome on S/O. Still IMHO the people deserve some warm and welcome advice to professionally grow further